# How to convert an entire column of time into seconds (under 24 hours) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hi all, I'm new to SQL and don't know anything about this DB. I need help in solving the following problem.

I want to convert the **TimeC** column into seconds and make a new column beside it. For example, in the very first row which has the value **00:08:22**, I would like to know how many seconds have gone passed since **00:00:00**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec ?

Comment: Linked some dupes with various ways, including how to deal with odd time formats and milliseconds if you have them in future. The basic advice is to just fire your time into TIME_TO_SEC though